# Transformation of distribution

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\tau \sim Uni([0,1])$ and define the stochastic process $X(t), t\in [0,1]$ as

$$X(t):= \frac{1}{t-\tau} \mathbb I_{t>\tau}$$

For fixed $t$, what is the distribution of $X(t)$?

A problem seems to be the divergence for $t\mapsto \tau$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $x\gt0$, $[X(t)\geqslant x]=[\tau\geqslant t-1/x]$ hence $\mathbb P(X(t)\geqslant x)=1-(t-1/x)$ for every $x$ such that $0\leqslant t-1/x\leqslant 1$ and $\mathbb P(X(t)\geqslant x)=1$ for every $x$ such that $t-1/x\leqslant 0$. The first condition reads $x\geqslant1/t$. Furthermore, $[X(t)=0]=[\tau\geqslant t]$ has probability $1-t$ hence
$$
\mathrm d\mathbb P_{X(t)}(x)=(1-t)\delta_0(\mathrm dx)+\frac1{x^2}\mathbf 1_{x\geqslant1/t}\mathrm dx.
$$